# Is there an available file GUI that can create a list of multiple files from multiple directories

Tags: r

I am trying to allow input of a list of files that can come from multiple directories. Previously I built the following in VB to do this. Is there something out there in R that is available and would provide this functionality? All the file choosers I can find will allow multiple files but seemingly only from a single directory unless I am missing something. Thanks.
[image: VB File Selection]

Comment: Can you post a sample of the directory-tree with the re;levant files?

Comment: That is what the image is meant to convey. And any file and directory could be relevant. I have not actually selected any files in this example, is that what you mean?

Comment: `list.files()` has a `recursive`-attribute. So that should get you your relevant files out of multiple subdirecrtories within the given path. example: `list.files(path = "g:/", pattern = ".*\\.gcd$", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)`